# I want to have margin:left for my a links in navbar, but i dont want border-bottom to move. How can I do it?

Tags: html, css

in my nav a part in css, when i do margin-left: border - bottom moves with a link too. But that is not something i want. How can i let border bottom stay where it stays, but give margin-left for my links in navbar?
I tried to search but I couldn't find a solution to this. Please help.

The question wants me to add more details, but I added all, so just filling down to meet the requirement to ask this question.

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color:rgb(245, 215, 169);
    line-height: 1.5;
}

main:not(nav) {
    width: 80%;
    margin:10px 10px 10px 230px;
}
    
.intro {
    text-align: center;
}  
    
header {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
nav a{
    display:block;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top:10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: solid gray 2px;
    cursor:grab;
} 
nav {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:220px;
    height: 100%;
    border-right:solid;
    border-color: rgba(0, 22, 22, 0.4);
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main id="main-doc">
        <section class="main-section" id="introduction">
            <header>Introduction</header>
            <p>JavaScript is a cross-platform, object-oriented scripting language. It is a small and lightweight language. Inside a host environment (for example, a web browser), JavaScript can be connected to the objects of its environment to provide programmatic control over them.</p>
            <p>JavaScript contains a standard library of objects, such as Array, Date, and Math, and a core set of language elements such as operators, control structures, and statements. Core JavaScript can be extended for a variety of purposes by supplementing it with additional objects; for example:</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Client-side JavaScript extends the core language by supplying objects to control a browser and its Document Object Model (DOM). For example, client-side extensions allow an application to place elements on an HTML form and respond to user events such as mouse clicks, form input, and page navigation.</li>
                <li>Server-side JavaScript extends the core language by supplying objects relevant to running JavaScript on a server. For example, server-side extensions allow an application to communicate with a database, provide continuity of information from one invocation to another of the application, or perform file manipulations on a server.</li>
            </ul>


        </section>

        <section class="main-section" id="hello_world">
            <header>Hello world</header>
            <p>To get started with writing JavaScript, open the Scratchpad and write your first "Hello world" JavaScript code:</p>
            <code>function greetMe(yourName) { alert("Hello " + yourName); }
                greetMe("World");
            </code>
            <p>Select the code in the pad and hit Ctrl+R to watch it unfold in your browser!
            </p>
            
        </section>


        <section class="main-section" id="variables">
            <header>Variables</header>
            <p>You use variables as symbolic names for values in your application. The names of variables, called identifiers, conform to certain rules.
            </p>

            <p>A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or dollar sign ($); subsequent characters can also be digits (0-9). Because JavaScript is case sensitive, letters include the characters "A" through "Z" (uppercase) and the characters "a" through "z" (lowercase).</p>

        </section>



        <section class="main-section" id="declaring_variables">
            <header>Declaring variables</header>
            <p>You can declare a variable in three ways:</p>
            <p>With the keyword var. For example,</p>
            <code>var x = 42.</code>

            <p>This syntax can be used to declare both local and global variables.
            </p>
            <p>By simply assigning it a value. For example,</p>
            <code>x = 42.</code>

            <p>This always declares a global variable. It generates a strict JavaScript warning. You shouldn't use this variant.
            </p>
            <p>With the keyword let. For example,</p>
            <code>let y = 13.</code>


        </section>



        <section class="main-section" id="constants">
            <header>Constants</header>
            <p>You can create a read-only, named constant with the const keyword. The syntax of a constant identifier is the same as for a variable identifier: it must start with a letter, underscore or dollar sign and can contain alphabetic, numeric, or underscore characters.</p>
            <code>const PI = 3.14;</code>

        </section>

        <nav id="navbar">
            <header class="intro">Javascript Documentation</header>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#introduction">Introduction</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#hello_world">Hello world</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#variables">Variables</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#declaring_variables">Declaring variables</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#constants">Constants</a>


        </nav>

    </main>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a "margin" but don't want the border to move. You can use CSS [text-indent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent)

only add this lines to CSS:

```
#navbar > a {
  text-indent: 10px;
}
```

Result looks like so:

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color:rgb(245, 215, 169);
    line-height: 1.5;
}

main:not(nav) {
    width: 80%;
    margin:10px 10px 10px 230px;
}
    
.intro {
    text-align: center;
}  
    
header {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
nav a{
    display:block;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top:10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: solid gray 2px;
    cursor:grab;
} 
nav {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:220px;
    height: 100%;
    border-right:solid;
    border-color: rgba(0, 22, 22, 0.4);
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
}

#navbar > a {
  text-indent: 10px;
}
```

```html
<main id="main-doc">
        <section class="main-section" id="introduction">
            <header>Introduction</header>
            <p>JavaScript is a cross-platform, object-oriented scripting language. It is a small and lightweight language. Inside a host environment (for example, a web browser), JavaScript can be connected to the objects of its environment to provide programmatic control over them.</p>
            <p>JavaScript contains a standard library of objects, such as Array, Date, and Math, and a core set of language elements such as operators, control structures, and statements. Core JavaScript can be extended for a variety of purposes by supplementing it with additional objects; for example:</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Client-side JavaScript extends the core language by supplying objects to control a browser and its Document Object Model (DOM). For example, client-side extensions allow an application to place elements on an HTML form and respond to user events such as mouse clicks, form input, and page navigation.</li>
                <li>Server-side JavaScript extends the core language by supplying objects relevant to running JavaScript on a server. For example, server-side extensions allow an application to communicate with a database, provide continuity of information from one invocation to another of the application, or perform file manipulations on a server.</li>
            </ul>


        </section>

        <section class="main-section" id="hello_world">
            <header>Hello world</header>
            <p>To get started with writing JavaScript, open the Scratchpad and write your first "Hello world" JavaScript code:</p>
            <code>function greetMe(yourName) { alert("Hello " + yourName); }
                greetMe("World");
            </code>
            <p>Select the code in the pad and hit Ctrl+R to watch it unfold in your browser!
            </p>
            
        </section>


        <section class="main-section" id="variables">
            <header>Variables</header>
            <p>You use variables as symbolic names for values in your application. The names of variables, called identifiers, conform to certain rules.
            </p>

            <p>A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or dollar sign ($); subsequent characters can also be digits (0-9). Because JavaScript is case sensitive, letters include the characters "A" through "Z" (uppercase) and the characters "a" through "z" (lowercase).</p>

        </section>



        <section class="main-section" id="declaring_variables">
            <header>Declaring variables</header>
            <p>You can declare a variable in three ways:</p>
            <p>With the keyword var. For example,</p>
            <code>var x = 42.</code>

            <p>This syntax can be used to declare both local and global variables.
            </p>
            <p>By simply assigning it a value. For example,</p>
            <code>x = 42.</code>

            <p>This always declares a global variable. It generates a strict JavaScript warning. You shouldn't use this variant.
            </p>
            <p>With the keyword let. For example,</p>
            <code>let y = 13.</code>


        </section>



        <section class="main-section" id="constants">
            <header>Constants</header>
            <p>You can create a read-only, named constant with the const keyword. The syntax of a constant identifier is the same as for a variable identifier: it must start with a letter, underscore or dollar sign and can contain alphabetic, numeric, or underscore characters.</p>
            <code>const PI = 3.14;</code>

        </section>

        <nav id="navbar">
            <header class="intro">Javascript Documentation</header>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#introduction">Introduction</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#hello_world">Hello world</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#variables">Variables</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#declaring_variables">Declaring variables</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#constants">Constants</a>


        </nav>

    </main>
```

**OR you can also use "padding" instead of "margin" like**

```
#navbar > a {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

the result looks the same:

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color:rgb(245, 215, 169);
    line-height: 1.5;
}

main:not(nav) {
    width: 80%;
    margin:10px 10px 10px 230px;
}
    
.intro {
    text-align: center;
}  
    
header {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
nav a{
    display:block;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top:10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: solid gray 2px;
    cursor:grab;
} 
nav {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:220px;
    height: 100%;
    border-right:solid;
    border-color: rgba(0, 22, 22, 0.4);
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
}

#navbar > a {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<main id="main-doc">
        <section class="main-section" id="introduction">
            <header>Introduction</header>
            <p>JavaScript is a cross-platform, object-oriented scripting language. It is a small and lightweight language. Inside a host environment (for example, a web browser), JavaScript can be connected to the objects of its environment to provide programmatic control over them.</p>
            <p>JavaScript contains a standard library of objects, such as Array, Date, and Math, and a core set of language elements such as operators, control structures, and statements. Core JavaScript can be extended for a variety of purposes by supplementing it with additional objects; for example:</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Client-side JavaScript extends the core language by supplying objects to control a browser and its Document Object Model (DOM). For example, client-side extensions allow an application to place elements on an HTML form and respond to user events such as mouse clicks, form input, and page navigation.</li>
                <li>Server-side JavaScript extends the core language by supplying objects relevant to running JavaScript on a server. For example, server-side extensions allow an application to communicate with a database, provide continuity of information from one invocation to another of the application, or perform file manipulations on a server.</li>
            </ul>


        </section>

        <section class="main-section" id="hello_world">
            <header>Hello world</header>
            <p>To get started with writing JavaScript, open the Scratchpad and write your first "Hello world" JavaScript code:</p>
            <code>function greetMe(yourName) { alert("Hello " + yourName); }
                greetMe("World");
            </code>
            <p>Select the code in the pad and hit Ctrl+R to watch it unfold in your browser!
            </p>
            
        </section>


        <section class="main-section" id="variables">
            <header>Variables</header>
            <p>You use variables as symbolic names for values in your application. The names of variables, called identifiers, conform to certain rules.
            </p>

            <p>A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or dollar sign ($); subsequent characters can also be digits (0-9). Because JavaScript is case sensitive, letters include the characters "A" through "Z" (uppercase) and the characters "a" through "z" (lowercase).</p>

        </section>



        <section class="main-section" id="declaring_variables">
            <header>Declaring variables</header>
            <p>You can declare a variable in three ways:</p>
            <p>With the keyword var. For example,</p>
            <code>var x = 42.</code>

            <p>This syntax can be used to declare both local and global variables.
            </p>
            <p>By simply assigning it a value. For example,</p>
            <code>x = 42.</code>

            <p>This always declares a global variable. It generates a strict JavaScript warning. You shouldn't use this variant.
            </p>
            <p>With the keyword let. For example,</p>
            <code>let y = 13.</code>


        </section>



        <section class="main-section" id="constants">
            <header>Constants</header>
            <p>You can create a read-only, named constant with the const keyword. The syntax of a constant identifier is the same as for a variable identifier: it must start with a letter, underscore or dollar sign and can contain alphabetic, numeric, or underscore characters.</p>
            <code>const PI = 3.14;</code>

        </section>

        <nav id="navbar">
            <header class="intro">Javascript Documentation</header>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#introduction">Introduction</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#hello_world">Hello world</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#variables">Variables</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#declaring_variables">Declaring variables</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#constants">Constants</a>


        </nav>

    </main>
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, @caramba , i dont know why i couldnt think of padding. But i didnt know text-indent. Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

In your css code try this,

```
nav a{
       text-align: center;
}
```

or

```
nav a{
       text-indent: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I didnt want to center them, but thank you, text-indent works.